# how to change the system image color of the button with objctive-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

As a novice, I want to ask how to change the system image color of the button in the way of code. I used to operate in storyboard. I tried to use btn Tintcolor and btn imageView. Tintcolor to modify, and titlecolor, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic example:

```
// create a button
UIButton *b = [UIButton new];

// set its title
[b setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set the "normal" title color to White
[b setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set the "highlighted" title color to Light Gray
[b setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

// set the background color to Blue
[b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

// get a system image with Template Rendering
UIImage *img = [[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"person.circle.fill"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

// set the button's image
[b setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set the image tint color to Red
[b setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Result:

[image]